# How can I use CSS variables to style components in svelte?

Tags: css, svelte, vite

Here's a very simple component `Text.svelte`, using a CSS variable in order to avoid duplication:

```html
<div>
    <span class="t1">t1</span> <span class="t2">t2</span>
</div>

<style>
    :root {
        --color: #f08080;
    }
    .t1 {
        border: solid var(--color);
    }
    .t2 {
        color: var(--color);
    }
</style>
```

It seems to work fine on its own, but if a parent component also happens to set `--color` then the parent can override it, which I don't want. Here's an example `App.svelte`:

```html
<script>
    import Text from './Text.svelte';
</script>

<Text/>
<div>app</div>

<style>
    :root {
        --color: #00ff00;
        color: var(--color);
    }
    div {
        border: solid 5px var(--color);
    }
</style>
```

Here's the svelte repl: https://svelte.dev/repl/224a088415794bdebc4f7ed71a6659d1?version=4.2.0

Strangely, in the svelte repl, everywhere `--color` is used is coloured red, but when I run it locally it's all coloured green. What am I doing wrong here, and what are the alternatives? I'm guessing I shouldn't be setting CSS variables within `:root` blocks in components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should indeed not use `:root`, it breaks the [scoping](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-components#style) by applying the property to the document element (`html`).

If you want to be able to use a property on any element within the component, just use `*` as a selector, which is transformed to a simple class.

```css
* { --color: #f08080; }

/* Example compiler output: */
.svelte-ggmrpx { --color: #f08080; }
```

The child's definition will override the parent's definition locally, as it is further down the hierarchy.

Comment: This is good! Alternatively, I've simply been putting `class="root"` on the root element(s) of the component.